# ERROR: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 715: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

I am using Python Notebook to open this text file in Windows 10. However UTF-8 encoding isn't working. How should I solve this error?

Comment: What is the source of this file? This character isn't in unicode encoding, so that would be the first place I would look. If you can open it in notepad without it looking ridiculous, then I can't help you. You could post a link to the text file to help us help you.

Comment: The source File is a Wikimedia Dump File which has been converted to a text file.

Comment: Can you post a link to the specific file?

Answer (score 1):

Python is trying to open the file using your system's default encoding, but the bytes in the file cannot be decoded with that encoding.

You need to pass the correct encoding to `open`.  We don't know what the correct encoding is, but the most likely candidates are UTF-8 or, less common these days, latin-1.  So you would do something like

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        # do something with the line
```